# puppet server suddenly stop working

Tags: puppet

I am new to `puppet`, it was working just fine till some days ago. I got back to start the server today, running

```
sudo /etc/init.d/puppetserver start
```

I then got

```
    Starting puppetserver (via systemctl): puppetserver.serviceJob for puppetserver.service failed. See 'systemctl status puppetserver.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

and `journalctl -xn` throws

```
No journal files were found.
 failed!
```

When I check the logs in `/var/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver`, I get no specific informations. I also noticed that the `puppet` command that was located in `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin` but I can't find the `bin` folder anymore.

Does anyone has an idea ?

EDIT : 
Here's the output of `systemctl status puppetserver.service`

```
puppetserver.service - LSB: puppetserver
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/puppetserver)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-11-10 10:20:13 UTC; 3h 54min ago
  Process: 5490 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/puppetserver start (code=exited, status=2)
```

and

Comment: is `opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin` in your `$PATH`?

Comment: This is very a strange behaviour.  check if puppet was installed in another directory. if not you have to reinstall puppetserver again.

Comment: Note the helpful systemd info at the end: `systemctl status puppetserver.service` and `journalctl -xn`. What is the output of those (you should do the `journalctl` immediately after the failure)?

Comment: @MattSchuchard thank you for your response, I edited accordingly my post

Comment: @bangbang yes I have it in my `PATH`

Comment: I'm inclined to think that your Puppet installation has been damaged.  I haven't enough information to venture a more specific guess.